# how to get extract a word from a line in bash shell script

Tags: bash

i want to extract a word from a sentence in bash script .it uses both coma and space as separators.

```
ex:- date=crossed 122 name=foo , userid=234567 , sessionid=2233445axdfg5209  associd=2
```

I have above sentence in which the interesting part is name=foo .the key name is always same but the string foo may vary. also other parameters may or may not be there .

i need to extract above  key value pair.
so output would be :

```
name=foo
```

what is the best way to do it  in shell script?

thanks!

Comment: Is there always a blank and a comma after every "foo" key? May the "foo" key contain blanks?

Answer (score 9):

grep is useful here:

```
grep -o 'name=[^ ,]\+'
```

Comment: when i run this i don't get any output...

Comment: you need to provide some input. Try `grep -o 'name=[^ ,]\+' <<< "$sentence"` assuming the sentence in your question is stored in the variable "sentence"

Answer (score 3):

If you know that the value after `name` will never contain spaces or quotes, and there are no other complications, you could do this with a `sed` one-liner:

`sed -e 's/^.*\(name=[^ ,]*\).*$/\1/'`

That just says to replace the entire line with the part that matches `name=` followed by any number of non-comma, non-space characters.

This not going to be terribly robust if there are possibilities like `name="quoted string"` or `name=string\ with\ escaped\ spaces`. But it will work for the limited case.

If you want to store the result in a shell variable you might do something like (in bash)

```
pair=$(echo $input | sed -e 's/^.*\(name=[^ ,]*\).*$/\1/')
echo $pair
```

which prints `name=foo`, as intended.

Tested with GNU sed 4.2.1 and Bash 4.2.10

Comment: Updated to say you can do exactly the same thing more elegantly by replacing the `sed` command above with `egrep -e 'name=[^ ,]*' -o`, where the `-o` means to only print out the matching portion of the line.

Comment: tried both on on SuSE11 , not sure what is the bash version..the first one doesnt show the output , the second one keeps running and dont exit.

Comment: See Glenn's comment on his answer (which is simpler and better than mine anyway). Where is your input coming from -- a file, stored in a shell variable, or something else?

Answer (score 2):

If "name=foo" is always in the same position in the line you could simply use:
`awk '{print($3)}'`, that will extract the third word in your line which is `name=foo` in your case.

Comment: He told "also other parameters may or may not be there" hence you may not use a positional logic.